# List only the current date register, if the date is not current, use the filter

Tags: php

So, how do I solve this problem? I want to list only the clients of today's date in case the client needs to search for a date earlier than the filter. That way it works only today, but when I select an earlier date it does not show.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($dados); $i++)
    {
        if(date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dados[$i][data])) == date("d/m/Y")){

        $dadosPaciente = $pacientes->loadPaciente($dados[$i][paciente]);
        $dadosDentista = $dentistas->loadDentista($dados[$i][dentista]);

        $total+=$dados[$i][total];

        echo "
            <tr>    
                <td style='line-height: 33px;'>".$os->getModoPagamento($dados[$i]["modo_pagamento"])."</td>
                <td style='line-height: 33px;'>".$dados[$i][id]."</td>
                <td style='line-height: 33px;'>".date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dados[$i][data]))."</td>
                <td style='line-height: 33px;'>".mb_convert_case(utf8_encode($pacientes->retornaDados('nome')), MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8")."</td>
                <td style='line-height: 33px;'>".mb_convert_case(utf8_encode($dentistas->retornaDados('nome')), MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8")."</td>
                <td style='line-height: 33px;'>R$ ".$moeda->formatar($dados[$i][total])."</td>
                <td style='line-height: 33px;'>".$os->getStatus($dados[$i][status])."   </td>
            <td>
```

Comment: In English, please.

Comment: Can you show us what is in `$dados` and what you expect to see as output?

Comment: So, how do I solve this problem? I want to list only the clients of today's date in case the client needs to search for a date earlier than the filter. That way it works only today, but when I select an earlier date it does not show.

For ($ i = 0; $ i <count ($ data); $ i ++) {

If (date ("d / m / Y", strtotime ($ data [$ i] [data])) == date ("d / m / Y")) {// content

Comment: Please tell us in English or go to [spanish SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: List only the current date register, if the date is not current, use the filter

Comment: Thanks @delboy1978uk.